# Hibernate select with distinct - how does it work with an inner join?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, distinct

First, I'm a total Hibernate novice.

Within hibernate, if you have an object, say author and author has a collection of books (say the list name is 'books'). If you run a Hibernate query, using using the following query I made up (not yet tested)

```
select distinct author from Author author inner join author.books as book
```

What exactly will the distinct do here?

The reason I ask is because I haven't selected a particular property in the select clause, such as

```
select distinct author.name ...
```

Also, what exactly will be unique about the objects which are returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if authors co-write books, you have a many-to-many association, and not a one-to-many.

That said, the query will return the list of all the authors who have written at least one book (that's the effect of the inner join). And each author will be exactly once in the returned list.

Comment: I've updated my question, thanks for the spot. And if it was a 1:N relationship instead of many to many?

Comment: My final question. I updated the schema so that it was 1:N instead of M:N. So I ran the query (without the distinct keyword) and I got several hundred records back. Then I included the distinct keyword and this number of records was reduced to only several records. How come I get so many records back when I omit the 'distinct' keyword? (When I have  a 1:N - between Author:book) In other words, what happens when the distinct keyword is omitted? Thanks for your help

Comment: When you don't use the distinct keyword, Hibernate returns a list containing one element for each JDBC row returned by the underlying SQL query. This means that you'll have the same instance of author many times in the returned list.

Comment: I had this feeling. But why would you have duplicate authors in the returned list if books is a collection within author? is this because (as you mentioned) you get 1 author joined with 1 book per row? thanks for your answers, it's very helpful.

Comment: Yes, that's it. See what the generated SQL query is, and execute it by yourself, and you will understand.